# Moving out of current domain

Tags: javascript

lets say I have many anchor links on my current web page and out of which some of the links are pointing to some different domains.

So what I want is to show a popup/message sort of stuff to the user before moving to different domain.

Solution 1 : After page loads we can bind click event to each anchor link and when the user clicks on any link we can check for the external link and show the message.

Q1. Is there any other optimized way which is better than Solution 1 ?

Q2. How to check whether the link taking you out of current domain / pointing to different domain than of current ?

Thanks,
bond.

Comment: You can do like FB - every link that leads to another site is redirected - fb.com?redirect=somelink or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other optimized way which is better than Solution 1 ?

Bind a single event to the document and check the click target. This is called [event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/)

> How to check whether the link taking you out of current doi

Check the `href` property of the link that was clicked

Comment: Thanks Quentin !

I tried just to check the same using below code snippet :

$(document).bind('click', function(event) {
   alert(event.target);
});

Will the previous bind event work, if I attach the above one on document.

I asked the above question because the site is already in place and we have lot more jquery code written for these links. and for some of the links we do have href = "javascript:void(0)" and in the bind event processing we are setting the href thro jquery code.

Comment: @Mr bond If you don't stop `Event` propagation the click `Event` will eventually bubble up to the `Document` level: so, yes it will work in combination.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the anchors and filter out those with `href` attributes containing a host portion, e.g. using a regular expression:

```
var r, l, i, n, o, a ;
    r = /(?:(http|https):\/\/)?([^\/]+)?(?:\/(.+))?/ ;
    l = document.getElementsByTagName("a") ;
    for( i = 0, n = l.length ; i < n ; i++ ) {
         o = l[i] ;
         if( !! ( s = o.getAttribute("href") ) ) {
             a = r.exec(s) ;
             if( !! a[2] ) //.. add your handlers to the A element
         }
    }
```

relative URLs, i.e. those that do not specify a host will not leave the current host.

You could then add a confirm dialogue to the click handler of links to remote hosts:

```
   //..
   function(href) {
       if( confirm("You are about to leave this website.\n\nAre you sure you want to continue?") ) window.location.assign(href) ;
   }
```

Where `href` is the value of the `href` attribute of the `A` element clicked.

---

Personally I don't agree with the solutions proposed that suggest monitoring *each and every* click `Event`. Usually you'll have a lot more click `Events` in your page lifecycle which do not entail a referal. In other words this will create unneccessary overhead.